# Trying to pass instance of an object to another class

Tags: java, object, instance

I have a Status object in my `DrawStatus` class that I would like to pass to my `FileStatus` Class. Currently my code is as follows given below:

```
public class DrawStatus extends JPanel{
    Status status = new Status();


    public DrawStatus(){

    }

    public Status getStatusObject(){
        return status;
    }
}
```

and this is the FileStatus class:

```
public class FileStatus {
DrawStatus status;
Status s;

public FileStatus(){
    s=status.getStatusObject();
}

public void writeToFile(){
    String file_text = s.getPedestrianStatusText() + "     " + s.getGatesStatusText() + "     " + s.getDrawBridgePositionText();
    System.out.println("\n" + file_text);
}
}
```

and the problem is that on the line

```
s=status.getStatusObject();
```

I get a NPE, and I am not sure why the object would be null. Any advice on how to fix this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized the `DrawStatus` variable in `FileStatus` class.

```
public class FileStatus {
DrawStatus status;
Status s;
```

So try to initialize it by doing something like:

```
public class FileStatus {
DrawStatus status = new DrawStatus();
Status s;
```

Comment: since DrawStatus is a JPanel that probably is attachend to other graphical elements, it would be better to pass it in as constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Is this reference initialized `DrawStatus status` before using that?

```
DrawStatus status=new DrawStatus();
```